# Spark - most efficient way to mimic update semantics

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Before I start I know Spark/Hive are not intended for CRUD style operations however...

I have had to reverse engineer some legacy TSQL code and it is easier to replicate the original CRUD style than to do a complete re-write.

I have come up with two potential approaches to provide update semantics on a table T.

### Approach A

1. Calculate the updated rows U.
2. Calculate unchanged rows (E) by performing an exclusion join between T and U
3. U.union(E)

### Approach B

1. Calculate the updated rows U.
2. Left join original table with U and select relevant U columns when U.key is not null, e.g.

`T.join(U, "inner").withColumn("a", when($"U.a".isNull, $"T.a").otherwise($"U.a"))`

Neither are particularly cheap however in many cases the updated Dataset U is small enough to broadcast.

Have I overlooked anything or indeed is there a more efficient approach I have not considered?

Cheers

Terry

Comment: Did you consider using a dedicated storage component for handling these "mutations" e.g. HBase/Phoenix, Kudu, Databricks Delta, Hudi? _(note that there is no Spark connector for writing to Hive 3 ACID yet but that could change)_

Comment: Ah, if you have S3-compatible storage, there's also Apache Iceberg.

Comment: I did consider using dedicated storage until I was informed that for the medium term I am limited to Dataset operations and Hive

Comment: I have seen this kind of brute-force, rebuild-all-history-every-day a couple of times. As history grows it becomes longer and longer, more and more expensive on I/O and memory, until the whole pipeline just crashes and burns. I advise you to change job after delivering it.

Comment: Believe me I have lobbied for more appropriate technologies to replatform these pipelines but to no avail. BTW I have already resigned!